# cant run this exe file from command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

https://sourceforge.net/projects/rtf2html/

I run

```
rtf2html "C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.rtf" test.html
```

and dont get any output?
Why? How to run this properly?

tried the cli options on github as well

```
rtf2html [<rtf file> [<html file>]]
```

https://github.com/lvu/rtf2html

Comment: You have to compile this before use. Have you did this?

Comment: its a exe file on source forge. Already compiled, not the github project

Comment: Oh, I am sorry for that. Try first: put exe and rtf at the same folder and see what happens. Ciao Italia.

Comment: tried that as well, get a empty html file or the system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Try another rtf, maybe a simpler one. Do you get any error message?

Comment: now it says rtf2html has stopped working

Comment: Are you shure you need the double quotation marks (") ? Maybe no, this could explain "system cannot find". Waw :p

Comment: yes I took out quotation marks now it says too many arguments

Comment: I was on mobile. Turning on PC now. Let's see. Caspita! This may have something to do with users permittions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114979/discussion-between-statosdotcom-and-ak0101).

Answer (score 0):

This soft, besides stating that can handle tables and bullets, seems not to endorse the promises (at least on my tests). For simple RTF it's ok. The way you are doing:

```
rtf2html infile.rtf outfile.html
```

Considering **.exe** and **.rtf** are on the same folder. Best.

Comment: Ak its everything ok? Need more help? Thanks.